# Factorial Trailing Zeroes

Tags: python-3.x

Given an integer n, return the number of trailing zeroes in n!.

Example 1:

Input: 3
Output: 0
Explanation: 3! = 6, no trailing zero.

Here's my code:

```
class Solution(object):
    def trailingZeroes(self, n):
    """
    :type n: int
    :rtype: int
    """
        def factor(n):
            if n == 0:
                return 1
            else:
                return n * factor(n - 1)

        num = factor(n)

        def helper(s, a):
            if s % 10 == 0:
                helper(s // 10, a + 1)
            else:
                return a

        return helper(num, 0)
```

Why does it return Null if s has tailing with zero???

Comment: There's an easier way. Hint: what does it mean for a number to have `n` trailing 0s?

Comment: @pault spoiler https://brilliant.org/wiki/trailing-number-of-zeros/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `return` the results of the call to `helper()` from within `helper()`:

```
    def helper(s, a):
        if s % 10 == 0:
            helper(s // 10, a + 1)
          # ^^^ There should be a "return" here in front of "helper"
        else:
            return a
```